# Second order homogeneous ODE, stuck at reducing the order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, maybe I do it wrong altogether, but here is my take:

$$x''-2x'+x=0 \\ x'=z \\ x''=\frac{dz}{dx}\cdot z \\ zdz-2zdx+xdx=0$$

So, here I don't  know what to do next, because I can't integrate $zdx$ for it will simply be $\frac{dz}{dx}$. What shoul I do?

Comment: In the title, the given equation is a second order homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: its homogeneous not the opposite

Comment: It's a really complicated method for a simple problem.

Comment: Why does the OP need to reduce the order instead of solving the auxiliary equation? Is the OP leaving out essential information in the body of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way to solve this...

Convert your differential equation to the characteristic equation $$c^2-2c+1=0$$

Factoring, you would get $$(c-1)^2=0$$

This means you would have the repeated root $$c=1$$

Repeated roots for the characteristic equation yield solutions to the differential equation in the form of $$Ae^t+Bte^t$$

Thus your solution is $$c_1e^t + c_2te^t$$ or $$e^t(c_1+c_2 t)$$

Comment: Why do you have this third constant $c_3$?

Comment: That was my error...it's been removed from the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asked to use substitution method then:
$$x''-2x'+x=0 $$
Rewrite it as
$$(x'-x)'-(x'-x)=0$$
Substitute $z=x'-x$
$$z'=z$$
This is a separable equation. Or use classical method for solution of second order linear equation.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
z \frac{dz}{dx} -2z +x=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Try the substitution $u=x/z$ ... You should get a seprable equation.